# Is it possible to power a monitor with 5 V if the power supply specification is DC 9-36 V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I'm attempting to turn an NES clone into a handheld device, therefore adding a power supply and a monitor as well as a few other minor things. After some research, I pulled all the parts together I needed and realized that the monitor I got says it takes DC 9-36 V but my power supply is 5 V as that's what the console requires. I've done some research and found a few answers saying that the monitor might be able to run at a lower voltage but nothing concrete. I'd rather not break/connect anything if I'm not sure that it can work. One suggestion I've seen is using a 12 V power supply instead and then using a step down regulator for the rest of the console to get the necessary 5 V. Although that may be my answer I was hoping I could find a way to make this work with what I already have if possible. If it wasn't already obvious, I'm not only new to here, but also electrical work like this. It's a new hobby but I'm trying my best to learn my way through, any advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: A boost converter can be used to raise the 5V to the required voltage.

Comment: Could I use a boost converter in the chain directly before the monitor? I'm assuming I would want to set it at the lowest possible of 9v as well. And forgive my ignorance, but if it's running on a 5v rechargeable battery that would probably significantly reduce the battery life right?

Comment: Yes, you can use a boost converter only for the monitor part. Good converters can be highly efficient and thus waste little power. Thus the monitor's impact on battery life will not be changed much by the fact there's a boost converter.

Comment: Okay great, I'll give it a shot.  Thanks for the help! I want expecting an answer this fast

Comment: Make sure to use low ESR caps but not too big to avoid large inrush on the interface to avoid resonating ferrites.

Comment: Which interface are you referring to? I appreciate the advice, but I'm below ground level on electrical engineering. I've been trying to learn on my own for a few weeks now but as I'm sure you know that's a steep hill to climb. So if you don't mind I'd appreciate any extra detail! My best guess is you're referring to the boost converter mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 1):

You could go two ways:

1. Use a higher input voltage and step it down like you had mentioned
2. Use the lower 5V voltage and use a boost converter to power the monitor alone

However, after reading some of your comments about powering this thing with a 5V battery and you being new to electronics I have to warn you about the following. Even if you use a 5V battery you **will** need a voltage regulator after it because batteries never offer constant voltage. Instead they start at a high voltage (i.e. 5.5V) when fully charged and can decrease their voltage when they lose charge. There's no way escaping a regulator after a battery.

Therefore, I would recommend going with a higher voltage battery (i.e. 9V or 12V) and use a step down converter for your digital and a boost converter for your monitor.

[image]

Comment: For the battery I have a 3.7 V lithium rechargeable battery and also one of these (Adafruit PowerBoost 1000 Charger - Rechargeable 5V Lipo USB Boost @ 1A - 1000C). Would this work if I chose the boost converter route? And if I went with a 12 V battery would I still need the boost converter for my monitor if it already only needs 12 V? Or are you suggesting that I step down the 12 V to 5 V and then use the boost converter to bring it back up to 12 V? Sorry for the big line of questions, I just want to make sure I fifire everything out before making any big moves

Comment: No worries! I think the big takeaway is that you will need 2 voltage regulators independent of the battery voltage you choose. The only thing that the battery will influence is whether you need 2 buck converters or 1 buck and 1 boost converter.

The reason for it is that battery voltage is unregulated and even though the battery might say it's 12 volts, that's under nominal conditions. However, battery voltages will fluctuate quite a bit depending on the amount of charge you have left on the battery. Just google "battery voltage graph" and you'll realize what I'm talking about

Comment: I would recommend using the 12V and use a dc/dc converter from 12V to 5V for your digital and another dc/dc converter for 12V to 9V for your monitor. You could also do 12V to 11V to maximize efficiency.

FYI you could also use LVRs but their efficiency would be very low since efficiency is Vin/Vout while buck converters will guarantee at least a 90% efficiency if not more.

Comment: Okay I think I'm starting to understand a bit better. What I'm modifying here is a Retron NES clone console. On the board for the console there's a 5v regulator that I had planned to tie into to supply power to the board, as well as chain that over to the boost converter for the monitor, are you saying I would also want to have a 12v regulator after the boost converter? This is all assuming I'm going the 5v battery route. I was considering the 12v battery route but from what I can tell I won't be able to find any decent 12v rechargeable battery that will fit in the case.

Comment: Do you think it's necessary or would I be able to get away with the 3.7v battery connected to the adafruit powerboost?

Comment: Unfortunately it is still an unregulated voltage. Would it work? Possibly yes, is it a good solution? No. If you want it to be battery operated then having it always plugged would defeat the purpose of battery operated :)

If you don't care about it being plugged, then get yourself an adapter that puts out 12V DC for your monitor and then you only need a buck converter or LVR to step it down to 5V for your logic

Comment: You're saying the voltage going to the monitor would be an unregulated voltage? Could I use a 12v voltage regulator after the boost converter or would that still be sketchy?

Comment: I believe you're misunderstanding what I'm saying. Let me put a block diagram together and I'll give you your options. I'll do it later tonight. Cheers!

Comment: I apologize for being so behind here, and I hope you don't mind but I'd really appreciate that, thanks!

Comment: I just saw the diagram now, thank you for drawing it out! That really helps. So if I was going with case 2 (and I understand this isn't the preferred route) would it work if I was to use the 3.7 v lithium battery going through the adafruit powerboost which boosts the voltage to 5.2v? Like I said the board for the console has a 5v regulator already so would that work in the place of the LDO? The main reason I prefer the battery setup I have is it has options for a charging port and an enable switch, but if it won't work then it won't work